# How to get return of index of minimum and maximum value in array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I am doing my homework where I should get maximum and minimum index in an array.
I already did that, but I can't understand how to make a return of this index.

```
package MaxMinArrayIndex.bozhko;

public class MaxMinArrayIndex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    gettingIndex();
}

private static int gettingIndex(int[]) {

    int[] myArray = {35, 2, 64, -18, 1000, 10000};
    int max = myArray[0];
    int indexForMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        int score = myArray[i];
        if (max < score) {
            max = score;
            indexForMax = i;
        }
    }
    int min = myArray[0];
    int indexForMin = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        int score = myArray[i];
        if (min > score) {
            min = score;
            indexForMin = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could return an `Array` or `List` with two `Integers`. The first is always the min. The second is always the max. You could also use a `Pair`. You could also create your own `Pair` like object that holds a max and min value.

Comment: You can't return two variables at same time. You can split it in two functions. One for maximum and one for minimum. Or, if you want to keep one function you can create and array with size 2 - `int[] indexes = new int[2]` and put on position 0, index for minimum, and on position 1, index for maximum and `return indexes`

Answer (score 0):

You should split your code into two functions: `getMinIndex()` and `getMaxIndex()`.

Something like:

```
static int getMinIndex(int[] array) {
    int min = array[0];
    int indexForMin = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int score = array[i];
        if (min > score) {
            min = score;
            indexForMin = i;
        }
    }

    return indexForMin;
}

static int getMaxIndex(int[] array) {
    int max = array[0];
    int indexForMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int score = array[i];
        if (max < score) {
            max = score;
            indexForMax = i;
        }
    }

    return indexForMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `new array` of length `2` and save the index in that array. Afterwards you can `return` that array.

Just like this:

```
public class MaxMinArrayIndex 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] indexes = new int[2];
        indexes = gettingIndex();
        System.out.printf("Min Index: %d\nMax Index: %d\n", indexes[0], indexes[1]);
    }

    private static int[] gettingIndex() 
    {
        int[] index = new int[2];
        int[] myArray = {35, 2, 64, -18, 1000, 10000};
        int max = myArray[0];
        int indexForMax = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (max < myArray[i]) {
                max = myArray[i];
                index[0] = i;
            }
        }

        int min = myArray[0];
        int indexForMin = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <     myArray.length; i++) {
            if (min > myArray[i]) {
                min = myArray[i];
                index[1] = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("MAX: %d \nMIN: %d\n\n", max,min);
        return index;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Your code won't accommodate the case where there are 2 equal Minimum or Maximum numbers in the array .

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to divide your methods in to two.

**Snipplet:**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray = {35, 2, 64, -18, 1000, 10000};
    int maxIndex = getMaxIndex(myArray);
    System.out.println("Max Index : "+ maxIndex);

    int minIndex = getMinIndex(myArray);
    System.out.println("Min Index : "+ minIndex);
  }

private static int getMaxIndex(int[] myArray) {

    int max = myArray[0];
    int indexForMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        int score = myArray[i];
        if (max < score) {
            max = score;
            indexForMax = i;
        }
    }
    return indexForMax;
  }

private static int getMinIndex(int[] myArray) {
    int min = myArray[0];
    int indexForMin = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        int score = myArray[i];
        if (min > score) {
            min = score;
            indexForMin = i;
        }
    }
    return indexForMin;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Max Index : 5
Min Index : 3
```